# Is it possible to access the different ports on a web server?

Tags: java, port, host

I created a game and I want to put it on online.  I want to buy a website (I'll probably use goddaddy to buy a domain name and use them as the web host) to use as the server to handle game play.  Because I would need a separate server for each game, I would need each game's server to exists on different ports.  So this leads to my question, is is possible to access these ports on my future web server? (I wrote the program in Java, so I would assume that I would access the ports from the server side by choosing a port for a ServerSocket, and from the client side by using the IP address from the website and the chosen port for a Socket)

(note: also, I am aware that it may be easier to simply use one port and run the servers on different threads instead, but I am just curious to have my question answered)

thanks a lot,
Ian

Answer (score 2):

Technically it is possible to use different ports, but I don't think that a webhoster like goddaddy will let you run a java process that binds to a special port.

Comment: Like I said below, thats interesting...do you know of any web hosting services that can do this? The cheaper the better of course. Thanks

Comment: no a don't know any provider that will allow this, because it may also provide some security issues

Answer (score 2):

If you mean that you are going to create your own TCP server you obviously can create as many instances of your server and configure them to listen to different ports. But it is year 2011 now. This solution was OK in early 90s.

I'd suggest you to use Restful API that works over HTTP. In this case you can forward calls to server side of each application using URL, e.g.

http://www.lan.com/foo/login?user=u123&password=123456 - log in into application foo

http://www.lan.com/bar/login?user=u123&password=123456 - log in into application bar

In this case you need only one server (the web server) that is listening to socket (port 80).
Your server side implementation could be done using various web techonlogis (php, java, asp.net etc) on your choice.

Comment: I think I like how this solution sounds so thank you, but I am a little confused so let me clarify a few things.  First of all, it might be helpful to let you know that yes, I am creating a TCP server, and also I plan to make the game into an applet on the website.  But I am a little confused about the client server model you proposed here; are you saying that I should set it up so my server (a Java program) will use "RESTful" to service clients (also Java programs) who send requests to port 80 (since it'll be an applet would the address be localhost?  or the URL?)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that should work. The security manager permits connections to a different port on the same IP address that the applet was loaded from.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a Java server on whatever port you want. Each server will accept incoming requests on one port.

The correct way is simply run on one port and each connection will instantiate a new servlet instance (which happens to run in its own thread) that can then service that request. You usually don't need to run separate ports or worry about concurrency, especially if all the stuff that's shared between connections (e.g. multiple players in one game) is handled through database read/writes.

Your host (GoDaddy) will have to allow you use of those ports, but if they are providing proper hosting (not virtual hosting) and given you your own IP there's no reason why you shouldn't be able to.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution may work theoritically, and I like AlexR's solution. But providers like godaddy doesnt let you run a java server, on ANY port. You will need to find out somebody who does. What I found is the cost goes up from $5/mo to about $20/mo, but you get a much better (read faster) machine. Good wishes, - MS.

Comment: Thats interesting...do you know of any web hosting services that can do this?  The cheaper the better of course.  Thanks

Comment: Look up www.slicehost.com - their 256MB slice with 10GB diskspace is $20/month